# Interpretation of the butterfly effect

Tags: philosophy-of-physics

It is said that in certain circumstances, a tiny change, like the flap of a butterfly's wings, can lead to enormous changes, like a tornado somewhere. However, it should be clarified what "change" means.

If the constantly changing state of the universe is determined by certain mathematical equations, then the *flap* has been part of the plan. The previous states of the the universe has dictated the flap.

**Updated**: If the butterfly didn't flap its wings, then it's not our universe. One might say I'm being too pedantic. So let's assume that the flap event is the only parameter changed in the state of the universe at the moment t. This assumption leads to one minor and one major problem.

1. The minor problem: Physical laws only allow consistent initial states. Changing only one parameter could result in an inconsistent state, so it will probably be necessary to change other parameters too, which might not be a tiny change anymore.
2. The major problem: If the mathematical equations predict that a tiny change in the state of the universe at the moment t will make the future course of the universe to increasingly diverge, what can be said if the same mathematical equations are used to compute the past of the universe? If they result in an increasingly diverging past course for the universe, then it's definitely not our universe.

Note: This question has been majorly edited under the influence of the great answers given.

Comment: Where do we need to think about violations or even laws?  The principle is that small causes can have very large effects.  Had the butterfly flapped its wings at a slightly different time, things might turn out quite differently.  That basic idea does not involve addressing the laws of physics as a whole or considering whether they get violated.

Comment: You should read [Wikipedia's Butterfly Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect). It means the same as sensitivity to initial conditions, and there is no need for violations, tiny or otherwise. There is a difference between laws and initial conditions, even if the latter are also "part of the plan".

Comment: Mathematical equations do *not* determine the exact state of the universe because, according to our current understanding (quantum mechanics, etc.), the universe is ***not*** deterministic.  Rather, those mathematical equations determine the boundaries of what is *possible*.  But even more so, our knowledge of the universe's current state is (necessarily) incomplete, and therefore suppositionally, we can speculate on whatever events we want (even in a deterministic universe) so long as they do not contradict our incomplete knowledge.

Comment: _"The previous states of the the universe has dictated the flap"_ That was classically true but quantum effects blow that out of the water. The universe is governed by probabilities. This is why (annoyingly) predeterminism is a largely vacant philosophical concept.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I'm more and more leaning to the multi-worlds model of quantum physics.  It saves determinism... except for the tiny little random factor of which branch of the universe you happen to be residing in right now.

Comment: @kbelder: I am totally there :D

Comment: *The truth is, in my opinion, the concept of cause and effect is a simplified model that is only suitable for isolated systems.* -> Isn't that exactly what the *butterfly effect* is supposed to mean ?

Comment: The butterfly caused the tornado? Bah, just another deity that doesn't take responsibility for their actions!

Comment: @Evargalo, That's a philosophical statement that happens to be consistent with the butterfly effect. You don't need the butterfly effect example to conclude that. The assumption that the universe is intertwined will do.

Comment: Ultimately to say 'the butterfly' flapping it's wings *caused* the tornado is to pick an arbitrary event in the whole sequence of causality.  You could Just as well say 'The butterfly being born caused a tornado, or  'the big bang caused a tornado'

Comment: Trying to grasp what "mathematical equations" you are referring to. Did we come up with a complete predictive model of the universe since the last time I checked? In the absence of actual predictive equations, any speculation about them is, well, speculation. If you gave me a set of such equations, the first thing I would do is feed them back to themselves. That is the only meaningful test I would believe. If absolutely nothing at all would be different, Voila! Perfect!

Comment: @nocomprende, that's just my way of assuming determinism. Even with non-determinism the problem 2 is present.

Comment: Mathematics is a tool, it is not reality. It does not control or predict reality, it is just a convenience to make our lives easier. A hammer is easier to pound nails with than a rock. That does not make hammers predictive of nailing, or superior to rocks in some way, or controlling of rocks. Thoughts and concepts do not control reality, they are just our way of trying to have some vague idea what the heck is going on. When you see an appealing concept, *run!*

Comment: Dear Asmani, please stop editing the post beyond recognition. If you have another question which is related and occurred due to the answers given, feel free to post an additional one instead, linking to this one as its context.

Comment: Simply because a computation is deterministic does not imply that it is computable.  Likewise, almost any nonlinear system (that's nearly everything, not just special cases or large systems) features chaotic behavior - a tiny difference in the initial condition explodes in influence until it overwhelms any reductionist attempt to predict it.  The error bars on your prediction must grow larger than the prediction itself with exponential speed.  Why anything is predictable in the face of this... that is unexplained.

Comment: Even assuming that the universe is not computable, the problem 2 is present. You can replace "mathematical equations" with physical laws. Or even more simply say that the state of the universe at T determines all the past and future states. That's determinism, right?

Comment: The Butterfly Effect is about placing limits on our ability to apply certain types of deterministic theories to make accurate predictions about the future.  It says nothing about the theory's correctness nor does it effect how a system evolves. It only says that we are limited in our ability to apply the theory to make predictions because we may not be able to measure all of the inputs sufficiently accurately in order to compute the correct output.

Answer (score 34):

I think you might be confusing determinism with what’s called ‘chaos.’  Chaotic systems are deterministic, nonlinear systems, which are characterized as ‘chaotic’ because of their extreme sensitivity to initial conditions. ‘Nonlinear,’ just means that they can be described by nonlinear differential equations.  The so-called ‘butterfly effect’ is a colorful way of illustrating this.

Nonlinear systems can be so sensitive to initial conditions that differences in how two computers handle floating point rounding errors can result in wildly different computational outcomes. This leads to a general inability to accurately predict nonlinear behavior, which can lead to confusion between chaotic and random systems . In practice, there may be no meaningful distinction, but in theory, chaotic systems are completely deterministic, whereas random systems (such as a quantum mechanical measurement) are taken to be fundamentally nondeterministic—meaning that the outcome is fundamentally not determined by the initial conditions.

Comment: "In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice, there is."

Answer (score 18):

You have clarified that you understand some descriptions of physics are about hypothetical well-isolated systems with different initial states.

However, when it comes to the Butterfly Effect you reject the concept of taking a well-isolated system with initial states, and demand that it explain the entire universe.

The Butterfly Effect describes a thought experiment involving a large apparatus (the Earth's entire atmosphere, at least) and posits that if it were possible to change the initial conditions (of the experiment - not of the entire universe), even a tiny change might lead to a vastly different conclusion.

It isn't intended to be an experiment that is feasible to conduct. It is intended to be a vivid model to explain some of the concepts of chaotic systems, that have real implications to modelling of real systems.

Comment: Thanks. Let's discuss the thought experiment. An advanced civilization is able to do this experiment on the Earth. Is it possible to have only "one" parameter changed in the initial conditions?

Comment: @Asmani: You're taking it way too literally. The point of a thought experiment is that it is *not a real experiment*. It's often not even possible, neither to conduct nor to validate the results, but ignores the impossibility in order to simply ask "what if". But yes, if you control the initial conditions, then by definition you can indeed change *one* parameter. It just might not be the one you're so fixated on.

Comment: This is a question of physics: Is it possible for a physical system to have two consistent states only differing in one parameter? Consider 2 electrons. If you change the position of one of them, then the electrical force that the second electron feels changes. It means two changes, not one, right?

Comment: @Asmani That's about definitions, not reality. You can consider the electrical force between two electrons to be separate from the position o the two electrons, or not. In reality ("to the best of our knowledge" etc.), each electron is a disturbance in the underlying electron quantum field, and the force between them is transferred via a different disturbance in the electro-magnetic quantum field. The behavior of both is governed by one equation. You can't change the two independently, so we don't consider them independent unless there's some reason to (e.g. for a thought experiment).

Comment: @Asmani So if our guess is indeed right and all that's around you is part of one equation that determines everything (and we figure out how to fill in the blanks we know about), you can't really change anything independently of anything else. But that doesn't mean the concept of change is worthless - it just means it isn't literally true, which is kind of true of most (all?) physics and science. We'd just say "change the position of one electron", and all the other "dependent changes" are implied in that. We use tools that help us, not tools that hinder our progress.

Comment: You are still playing at the wrong level. We all agree that it is not feasible to construct this experiment. Why? Because if the effect is true, we would need to construct a replica to infinite accuracy, which is impossible. However, if you posit an hypothetical civilisation with magic abilities to do X, and then, within the context of this hypothetical, ask if they can do X, the answer has to be a tautological "Yes, by definition".

Comment: More interestingly: If you do an actual experiment of dropping some hot liquid into some cold water, mix it, and measure the temperature, you get a certain roughly predictable result. You can reproduce it and get a very similar result. The more precisely you can prepare the masses, the purity, the temperature and the thermal isolation, the more precise your predictions of the answer will be.

Comment: If you do an experiment of dropping some ink into swirling water, and look at the shapes in the water, you get interesting chaotic patterns. Do it again, and get different patterns. No matter how precisely you measure the everything, no matter how precisely you try to reproduce the effects, you get different patterns.

Comment: If you can ever get the patterns to be predictable because you are getting more and more precise, then you have evidence against the system being chaotic.

Comment: The Butterfly Effect is just an illustration that the atmosphere is chaotic, and that precision will never be possible. Even the trivial difference between two situations as the wind from the flap of a butterfly might change the outcome in major ways.

Comment: @Oddthinking, In the context of our discussion, we can identify two types of hypothetical assumptions. One type assumes the physical laws are the same, but the states are different. Another type assumes that physical laws could be violated/different. Are you taking type 2 assumptions? If not, then according to what Luaan explained, you can't change only one parameter independently.

Comment: @Asmani: If you assume a civilisation with Type 1 powers that make it possible to reproduce a large experimental set up infinitely accurately excep that they can change one parameter independently, then you can't consistently say that in the hypothetical universe they are unable to do exactly that. [Not sure why we are still having this discussion here. I'll let you have the final word, and be done with it.]

Comment: Please do not use the comments section for discussion; [edit] your post if need be or use [chat].

Answer (score 15):

The butterfly effect is formally captured mathematically.  Consider a chaotic system (such as a mathematical equation of the weather) and an initial state.  If we use those equations, we can calculate what the state will be at some future time (say, 1 month in the future).  For this deterministic system, that is the only possible state we can be at in 1 month.

Now *perturb* the initial state slightly.  Pick a "nearby" state, such as a state where the butterfly is about to flap its wings instead of staying still.  Now use the same equations to calculate the state 1 month in the future.  For this deterministic system, there will be one and only one possible state that we can be at in 1 month.  However, because the system is chaotic, this state may be *drastically* different from the start in the first scenario.

Now this mathematical result points out two interesting physical outcomes.  The first is to note that the state of the weather in 1 month is *incredibly* hard to predict.  In theory, it's future state depends on how polarized or depolarized a few neurons within a butterfly's brain are -- the neurons which control wing flapping.  The idea that the future state of a system as large as the globe is highly sensitive to such a small detail is I, in my opinion, a pretty significant philosophical statement.

The other major result of this has us noting that we never measure anything *perfectly*.  There's always some error in our measurements.  This means we cannot predict the future state of such chaotic systems accurately.  It is a practical limitation to the capabilities of science.

It also implies that if we got the laws of the universe *slightly* wrong, we could measure everything perfectly and *still* not be able to predict the future state of chaotic things like the weather.  Or, as you suggest, if the consistency of the world's laws were suspended for a brief moment in a tiny place, the effects could still change very large systems.

As a final thought, the butterfly theory does indicate that if you were able to suspend the rules of physics in a deterministic chaotic universe and change one thing to a state that it wasn't, you would indeed cause widespread changes in the overall state of the universe.  God "changing a beetle" may indeed result in a tornado.  One might say "the beetle caused the tornado," or maybe one might just say "God caused the tornado, and used a beetle to do it."

As for cause and effect, I think mathematicians generally agree that it is an ineffective concept in chaotic systems.  It's not impossible to use, as you noted with the beetle causing a tornado, but it becomes less meaningful.  I find the more meaningful use of cause and effect is in situations which are stable in the presence of perturbations, where identifying a "cause" permits you to mostly ignore large numbers of other details which won't have a large change on the effect.  In chaotic systems, you can't ignore the other effects (because they could cause huge changes as well), so the benefit of identifying a "cause" is limited.

Comment: Pi is a transcendental number.

Comment: I believe this question centers around how one would go about "perturbing" the initial state without modifying the states that led to that initial state (and so on, to infinity), without violating some laws of physics.  They are arguing that the initial state is predetermined due to physics of everything that preceded it. - I think the answer comes down to the Butterfly Effect being a theory of *models*, not the *universe*.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, thank you, that's exactly what I was asking. Maybe write your comment as an "Answer" and I will check it as the answer.

Comment: @Asmani OddThinking's [answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/50483/19460) seems to pretty well align with what I was trying to get at.  Unfortunately, I don't have the time right now to type up an answer in way that would be up to standards.  My feelings won't be hurt if you accept that one.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I think you've rephrased my question much more eloquently than I did. I used your words in my question. Is that okay?

Comment: @BradleyUffner That's what I was trying to get at with my last two paragraphs.  I may need to add more.  If you have `the real universe`, and you have a `model` that *almost but not quite exactly* models the state of the universe, you would hope that it would *almost but not quite exactly* predict the future state of the universe.  In chaotic systems, that hope falls apart -- the future states quickly look nothing like your model predicted.

Comment: I'd say its similar to how we might call the order of a well shuffled deck "random."  It's not random.  There is exactly one order you are going to draw the cards in, which is the order they appear in that shuffled deck.  However, the shuffling process is designed to be chaotic, making it so that you can't effectively model the order of the cards in the shuffled deck any better than random.

Comment: Even if we get the laws of the universe (whatever those might be) exactly right, the fact that fundamental constants in most cases do not have a finite representation means that things will change very fast given any tiny variation in conditions, which is what the whole idea is about.

Answer (score 8):

The "butterfly effect" appears to be a modern variant of the ancient [philosophical axiom](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/catholicteaching/philosophy/axiomata.htm) "*Parvus error in principiis, magnus in conclusionibus*" or "*Parvus error in principio, magnus est in fine*":

> A small error in the beginning (or in principles) leads to a big error in the end (or in conclusions).

See [St. Thomas Aquinas](https://www.encyclopedia.com/people/philosophy-and-religion/philosophy-biographies/saint-thomas-aquinas#1G22830900131) [*De Ente et Essentia*](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeEnte&Essentia.htm), proemium, which references Aristotle [*De Cœlo* bk. 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeCoelo.htm#1-9), specifically [271<sup>b</sup>](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeCoelo.htm#1-9):

> …the least initial deviation from the truth is multiplied later a thousandfold. Admit, for instance, the existence of a minimum magnitude, and you will find that the minimum which you have introduced, small as it is, causes the greatest truths of mathematics to totter. The reason is that a principle is great rather in power than in extent; hence that which was small at the start turns out a giant at the end.

Upon which St. Thomas commentates ([*In De caelo* lib. 1 l. 9 n. 4 [97.]](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeCoelo.htm#1-9)):

> …one who makes a slight departure from the truth in his principles gets 10,000 [i.e., many] times farther from the truth as he goes on. This is so because all things that follow depend on their principles. This is especially clear in an error at the crossroads: for one who at the beginning is only a slight distance from the right road gets very far away from it later on.* And he gives, as an example of what he is talking about, the case of those who posited a smallest magnitude, as Democritus posited indivisible bodies. By thus introducing a least quantity, he overthrew the most important propositions of mathematics — for example, that any given line can be cut into two halves. The reason for this effect is that a principle, though small in stature, is nevertheless great in power, just as from a small seed a mammoth tree is produced. Hence it is that what is small in the beginning becomes multiplied in the end, because it reaches unto all that to which the power of the principle extends, whether this be true or false.

<sup>*St. Thomas's example here is exactly that of [*Chaos: A Mathematical Adventure*](http://www.chaos-math.org), [ch. 2 "Vector Fields"](http://www.chaos-math.org/en/chaos-ii-vector-fields), [9:10ff.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ninjc2sDFQ&index=2&list=PLw2BeOjATqruoac7tS6Clnn-mpxlRkXfV&t=9m10s); see also [*ibid.* ch. 7 "Strange Attractors & the Butterfly Effect"](http://www.chaos-math.org/en/chaos-vii-strange-attractors).</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Even if you assume determinism without quantum complications, I think a better interpretation (more consistent with Lorenz's original math) is this: Given a complete description of the state of the Universe at one point in time, calculating all the causes and effects forward may come to a point with, say, a hurricane in Florida. Suppose that we rewound back to that same initial state, and then made a small change--like removing the flap of a butterfly's wing in China. It's quite likely, then, that performing those exact same calculations on this new state for the same amount of time will result in a world without that hurricane.

Comment: But sooner or later there would be a hurricane *somewhere*. The atmosphere is unstable. Unpredictable. We can totally rely on that.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answers given so far, you view this question in the light of something you call a "plan" or "laws", which you just pulled out of thin air.

Question your presupposition. The butterfly effect is also an excellent philosophical tool to illustrate that there is no plan and cannot be. (the exact proof here is lengthy, but trivial)

Now what you might mean by these words is determinism, but if we have learnt anything in the past century, it is that determinism only exists as a law of averages on the macro scale. The main philosophical effect of the butterfly effect is to remind us of this, and of the fact that under certain circumstances, a tiny change in the underlying causes can cause a ripple effect that causes dramatic changes in the result.

The butterfly effect is only the most extreme example of that. Another great example from everyday life is what Gottmann calls "sliding doors". Imagine catching the train, and you are almost late. The fraction of a second that decides if you just make it or the doors close just in front of you can make you late for one hour (or more, depending on how often the train goes). That's a factor of 10,000 or so between cause and effect.

Maybe that more down-to-earth example helps to understand the butterfly effect also in a less abstract way.

Answer (score 2):

> "How one would go about 'perturbing' the initial state without modifying the states"

The difference in initial conditions is generally an imaginary one. Because what the effect really points to, is that any uncertainty in measurement of the current universe limits our ability to make predictions.

Determinism relies on the idea that current complexity came out of earlier simplicity that could be computationally manageable, and in principle predict now. But complexity of iterating from the simple inital condition would fundamentally that - not enough bits in the world to represent the world.

So determinism was always just a fantasy anyway, complete knowledge of the past or future was always impossible from inside the universe. It is really of theological concern only, whether God 'plays dice' from outside.

Comment: Even if determining the future is impossible in practice, the question of whether the universe is *fundamentally* deterministic or not is important - and I don't mean for theological/philosophical reasons. Even if determinism isn't 100% real, it's still a thing worth studying. It's not a black-and-white proposition, there's all sorts of shades of grey. You may not be able to predict accurately the path a baseball will take, but you still aim when throwing, don't you? You take into account reasonable risks, and do your best.

Comment: As for determinism being a fantasy, you don't need the complete knowledge of the past. You just need a snapshot, and a set of rules to follow. If you needed the whole past and future, what would be the difference between a deterministic and a non-deterministic universe? Both would give you the exact same answers regardless. The same way, you don't necessarily need to take into account the *whole* universe, if you're not looking for 100% accuracy - the butterfly effect is interesting in that it assumes a deterministic universe, and still shows that it doesn't necessarily mean predictability.

Comment: @Luaan You can't get a snapshot, that was my point - except possibly of infinitesimal microseconds after the big bang, which can't be iterated from - not least because the tiniest error from simplification needed to do calculations within the universe, could ripple into huge errors.

Comment: Because the fundamental constants are transcendental. See? It solves the whole question.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the thought experiment is that, there are things that are "either or," and some very small change may push some parameter of a system from one macro-state to another macro-state.

For a more vivid example, a specific human being's head may be 1mm away from the trajectory of a bullet, and the human survives. Later, that human may invent a cure for the common cold. A very small change to the initial state, if the head had been one inch off to the "wrong" side, would have had a very different outcome, and the common cold would not have been cured.

Other examples include a nail on the road in front of a car, being at enough of an angle to cause a flat tire, versus being slightly less than that angle and not causing a flat tire. Or a cat missing a jump up onto a ledge just barely and falling backwards/off, or just barely making it with enough space to claw its way up. In either of these cases, there is SOME "thin line" that determines the difference between success or failure. In fact, these kinds of systems are the vast majority of systems in our daily life, and thus we can't really "measure everything" and "run the computation" to simulate/predict the future.

These thought experiments are there to illustrate the vast outcome multiplier of seemingly small changes in input state in systems that are "chaotic" or "divergent." The experiment is not "flap or not flap a wing," or "move or not move a head," but instead, illustrations of the principle.

There exist chaotic systems we can actually run the A/B experiment on. It's most easily done in computer simulations, because there you can know it's 100% the same initial conditions, except for the one thing you change. But, as others have said, this is a tought experiment, intended to illustrate the concept of "large changes being predicated on very small differences in chaotic/divergent systems."

Finally:

> In order to be accurate, we can only say that the current state of the universe is caused by its previous states.

This is one place this train of thought can end up, and the final conclusion from that thought is not just that there are no gods, but also that there is no free will. I personally find this argument perfectly acceptable, and there's no testable hypothesis or experiment that has been able to demonstrate anything to the contrary.

Comment: The original butterfly concept came from computer simulations. A "cue ball" world with only dry atmosphere and sun shining on it = predictable, boring. Add some water vapor... Unpredictable. Like the 3 body problem.

Answer (score 0):

> It is said that in certain circumstances, a tiny change, like the flap of a 
>   butterfly's wings, can lead to enormous changes.

It's an image, **not to be taken literally**. All the billions of flaps of Butterfly wings cannot lead to big changes, because the displacement of air they cause is immediately lost in the white noise of all other air circulation anyway.

Same as in : "The Straw That Broke the Camel's Back", never in history has any Camels back been broken by adding a single straw.

Imagine you have (fair) dice. You throw it twice in **exactly** the same way. Do you think it will show the same number twice? No matter how hard you try to throw it exactly the same way, it will end up showing a different number, because even the slightest difference (butterfly's wing flap) will influence the throw.

Now imagine you throw a baseball, trying to hit a glove. You throw it twice exactly the same. Do you think you (or a competent thrower) can hit the glove twice? Sure they can, because it takes significant difference to make the ball miss the glove. So no matter how many butterflies are present, a good pitcher can make the ball hit a target.

So the number shown by a throw of dice is very sensitive to small changes, making it hard to repeat the same result or to predict, whereas hitting a glove with a baseball is a rather stable system not too dependent on small changes.

Answer (score 0):

Chaos theory produced this concept of the butterfly effect.

I think this is conceptually an illusion.
In lots of systems there are triggers and tendencies that grow and build to a massive extent, or fluctuate continually without any change.

So a system can exist, which is just about to set off this chain of events which is released by a small change.  It is not the small change that matters, but the whole build up of the system that was ready to be triggered by a small change.

In human systems take the liberation of Iraq, bringing democracy to a society that did not know what to do with it.  The trigger was there, but not the system that could take advantage of it.

Or Oliver Cromwell over throwing the King of England, yet could not trigger democracy and freedoms, to see the King return, and things progress slowly on.

Or the settlers in the USA, which led to the foundation of the country and the principles of self determination.  A small change in expectation but with a system that could implement it.